# Firestore- How to get the id of a user that contains a specific value?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My firestore structure contains a collection called `users`, that contains documents. Each user's document contains collection named `user-info` that includes the filed `email`.

**Here is a picture that describes the structure of the firestore:**
[image: my firestore structure]

How to get the User ID (in green) from a specific email (in red), which is in user-info?

The function I wrote in the ts file is:(Does not work)

```
...
export class UsersList implements OnInit {
  ...
  constructor(private router: Router, private authservice: AuthService,public crudservice:CrudService) {}
  ....
  get_UserID_from_email(someEmail)
  {
    let user;
    this.crudservice.get_AllUsers().subscribe(data => {
      user = data.map(c => {
        console.log(c.payload.doc.data()['user-info']['email']);
        if(c.payload.doc.data()['user-info']['email'] == someEmail)
          return c.payload.doc;
      })
    });
  }
  ...
}
```

and in crud.service.ts:

```
...
export class CrudService {
  constructor(private authservice: AuthService, public fireservices:AngularFirestore) { }
  ...
  get_AllUsers()
  {
    return this.fireservices.collection('users').snapshotChanges();
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: You need to look at the path of the document in `c.payload.doc` to find the name of the parent collection where it is organized.  That object should have properties or methods that let you walk up its parent collections/docs.

Answer (score 1):

Here I have wrote the function how to get the child collection data in firestore. Can you please try with this code?

```
  parentId: any;
  getUser(email) {
    let docRef = this.fireservices.collection('users');
    const users = docRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map((actions) =>
        actions.map((a) => {
          //this.parentId is your parent documentId which is in your image green color
          this.parentId = a.payload.doc.id;
          return docRef.doc(this.parentId).collection('user-info', ref => ref.where('email', '==', email)).valueChanges();
        })
      )
    );
    users.subscribe(data => {
      data[0].subscribe(child => {
        //Here you can get the child data which is in your image red color
        console.log(child[0]);
      });
    });
  }
```

Or else second way you can try with this code

```
  parentId: any = null;
  getUser(email) {
    let docRef = this.fireStore.collection('users');
    docRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map((actions) =>
        actions.map((a) => {
          //this.parentId is your parent documentId which is in your image green color
          let parentId = a.payload.doc.id;
          return docRef.doc(parentId).collection('user-info', ref => ref.where('email', '==', email)).snapshotChanges().pipe(map((child) => child.map((childData) => {
            const data = childData.payload.doc.data() as any;
            const childDocId = childData.payload.doc.id;
            return { parentId, ...data };
          })));
        })
      )
    ).subscribe(data => {
      data[0].subscribe(childData => {
        //Here you can got the parent document Id
        childData[0].parentId;
      })
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it! But in get_AllUsers(email) function, in the first "map" (in line 3) there is an error: `Cannot find name 'map'. Did you mean 'Map'?` Do you have an idea what cause the error? @Aman Gojariya

Comment: You need to import import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

Comment: Thanks! the error is gone! But what do I need to write instead of the`// Here you will get id and filtered data` in order to access the id? @Aman Gojariya

Comment: you need to just write data.id to get id of doc

Comment: I tried it, but I get the error: `Property 'id' does not exist on type '{ id: string; data: unknown; }[]'` Do you know what causes the error? @Aman Gojariya

Comment: Ohh Sorry @Mana , It will return the array so you can write data[0].id.

Comment: I really appreciate it, thank you, but when I print `console.log(data)` I get `[]`. And when I print `console.log(data[0].id)` I get the error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`. @Aman Gojariya

Comment: Hello @Mana , sorry for the inconvenience. I have updated the whole answer. Can you please try with this code.

Comment: thank you!!! @Aman Gojariya The code you wrote seems perfect to me, but for some unknown reason I accept in both cases you suggested the error in the console: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined` (in the row of `data [0] .subscribe`)

Comment: You can put the condition is if(data) on above data[0].subscribe

Comment: If my code is working perfectly then please mark as right and upvote please

Comment: Of course I will! @Aman Gojariya You are very helpful!  I put the condition is `if(data[0])` on above `data[0].subscribe`, and now there is no error in the console, but I do not enter into this condition, I always enter into the `else`.

Comment: @Mana Thank for your appreciation. I need to debug the code with your data. It's Possible?

Comment: If not then please refer this docs for your concern It will help you https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/0f6f2bf83c93a3a475bbfe4f7d37a6aa6fc1d03d/docs/firestore/documents.md

Comment: I have learn the firebase with angular using this docs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 get_AllUsers(){
      return await this.fireservices.collection('users').doc('user-info')
                       .where('email', '==', 'try1@gmail.com').get()
                       .then(doc => {
                          return doc;
                       }).catch(error => {
                          console.log(error);
                       });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it! But I get an error in `where` (the second line): `Property 'where' does not exist on type 'AngularFirestoreDocument<unknown>'.` Do you have an idea what cause the error? @Akash Bavale

Comment: @Mana It seems that I am using a different package altogether, try this one if it solves your issue 

"@google-cloud/firestore": "^1.2.0"

Answer (score 0):

```
    import { AngularFirestore, CollectionReference } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
    
    constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore){}
    this.firestore
              .collection('collectionName', (collectionRef: CollectionReference) =>
                collectionRef.where('email', '==', 'email')
              )
              .snapshotChanges()
              .subscribe((res) => {
                if (res.length > 0) {
                  this.user = res.map((e) => {
                    return {
                      id: e.payload.doc.id,
                      ...(e.payload.doc.data() as any),
                    };
                  })[0];
You can get user list. And if u console the id. You got the firebase data id.
```